# Finding the Laurent series of $\frac{-z^2-2z+3i}{z-2i}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Finding the Laurent series of

$$f(z) = \frac{-z^2-2z+3i}{z-2i}$$

on the annulus of infinite external radius $|z-i| > 1$

---

This function looks fairly messy. We clearly have a simple pole at $z=2i$. But it's not obvious to me how to find the principal and analytic part given this particular numerator. Any advice on how to obtain this expansion? Thanks

**UPDATE:** I attempted to rewrite this using long division. When doing so, I obtain

$$(-z^2-2z+3i) \div (z-2i) = -z-2-2i-\frac{i-4}{z-2i}$$

In other words, I obtained a remainder of $i-4$.

Not sure if this is helpful.

Comment: How you considered dividing the numerator by denominator?

Comment: @Buraian I just long divided it and got a nonzero remainder, if that's supposed to be the case

Comment: Could you add that into your question?

Comment: @Buraian I have updated the question now.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, if $|z-i|>1$,\begin{align}\frac1{z-2i}&=\frac1{-i+(z-i)}\\&=\frac i{1+i(z-i)}\\&=-i\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}\bigl(-i(z-i)\bigr)^n\text{ (because $\bigl|i(z-i)\bigr|>1$)}\\&=-i\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}(-i)^n(z-i)^n\\&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}(-i)^{n+1}(z-i)^n.\end{align}Can you take it from here?

Comment: Sum till -1? O_o

Comment: @Buraian Yes: if $|z|>1$,$$\frac1{1-z}=-\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}z^n.$$

Comment: @Buraian to elaborate, if $|z| > 1$ then $|1/z| < 1$ so $$\frac{1}{1-z} = -\frac{1}{z} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - z^{-1}} = -z^{-1} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (z^{-1})^n = -\sum_{n=0}^\infty = (z^{-1})^{n+1} = -\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} z^n.$$